# How lookup works in Database?

Tags: java, database

I'm trying to understand how lookups works in database. In database everything is on disk in file system.

So lets say If I query a data in table having millions of records with some filter clause, then all records will be loaded into memory first then 
it looks for specific data or something else happens ? Correct ?

My understanding says, What ever the query we run, all database table's data gets loaded into memory and then do the operations. Is it correct ?

Secondly, If I'm having 8gb of data in table and 4gb ram, That will work to get data from Database ? Usually it works, but Does it search on disk ? Really ?

Please share your views.

Thanks

Comment: No, the DBMS will not load the complete table into memory.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Then how it works ? Where search happens ?

Comment: It might, for example, load just a small index into memory to help figure out where in the file system to look, or tell it to go to a specific place in a file.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about relational databases using SQL, then your assumptions are wrong.

The database will not load all rows into memory at once to find just one. If there is an index on the column(s) in the where clause, that index will be used to lookup the row(s) needed.

If there is no index, the database might *read* one row after the other from the table(s), inspect the values  and will discard those that don't meet the filter criteria from the WHERE clause. So at any given time only a fraction of the rows are kept in memory (how much depends on the implementation of the database, the configuration and the execution plan chosen).

Database might resort to do operations on disk if the rows don't fit into memory. E.g. if a sort of the rows is needed, then this might be done on disk if there isn't enough memory to keep all rows in memory.

When the result is returned, it's also not held in memory. The exact way how it's done depends on the specific DBMS product.

Comment: Your second and fourth sentences are a contradiction.

Comment: @BasilBourque: why? Both sentences say that the rows are not hold in memory

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Lets say if its PostgreSQL. Then I want to select 10 millions of records out of 15 millions of records with some analytic functions. All records are indexed, then the moment I fire the query where it will filter the 10 millions of records first ? In disk ?

Comment: How does a database read rows if not by loading them into memory?

Comment: @Andrea: it will filter them while going through the index

Comment: @BasilBourque: the rows are read into memory but then discarded. I will clarify that I mean that not all rows are kept in memory at the same time.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, its going through index...Its okay..! My question is will it do in Disk or memory for selecting the chunk of data ?

Comment: @BasilBourque The OP assumed that the whole table would be loaded in memory **first**, which is definitely not the case. And given things like result set streaming (or batched fetching), it will usually not even have all selected rows in memory at one time.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simplified overview.

A serious relational database engine such as Postgres or MS SQL Server or Oracle is highly tuned to manage efficient access to data written to persistent storage while caching copies in memory.

## Database > Memory

The database loads data from storage into memory to work with it, to read and write it, just like any app. When memory fills up, data not currently needed is purged, then other data can be loaded from storage into memory. Modified rows are first altered in memory, then written to storage.

This means a stored database can be much larger than available memory. For example, you might have a terabyte (1,000 gigs) sized database in storage on a machine with 8 gigs of memory. For best performance, you want the database to have access to about as much memory as needed to fit all the data recently in use. More users with more threads doing more queries/inserts/updates means you will benefit from more memory. Only the recently used rows of the recently accessed tables need be in memory. Loading partial chunks of needed data from storage into memory as needed is the principal job of the database. So the entire database need not be loaded entirely into memory.

By default a query on a table causes each of the rows to be loaded into memory.

A copy of a row may be held in memory as a cache. Each database engine implementation has its own rules for deciding which rows should be held in the cache and for how long. The amount of memory used as a cache can be configured by the database administrator (DBA).

[image: diagram of database in storage with some rows copied into cache in memory]

The next time a table is queried and its rows are about to be loaded from storage, the cache in memory is first checked to see if a fresh enough copy of the row is present. If so, there is no need to load from storage. Using cached copy in memory is a huge performance boost.

Performing a query by examining each row is known as a *sequential scan* or similar terms.

If you know a particular column’s data will be the target of frequent queries, you would inform the DBA so she can tell the database  to build and maintain an index on that column. An index is like an old-fashioned card catalog in a library, where parts of a book such as title or author is copied and organized in its own sorted structure. Much easier to find an entry in the small drawer of a card catalog rather than walk though all the shelves in the library building to find your book.

The copied and sorted data in the index is kept in storage. Like rows, parts of the index may be kept in cache memory for faster searching.

When an index is present, the query engine will query it rather than query stored rows if feasible and efficient. Performing a query by going through the index rather than rows is known as an *indexed scan* or similar terms.

Indexes have a cost. They require work by the database, and require some space in storage. As rows are modified with changes to the data in an indexed column, the database must update the index as well as the row. And the database must do so in a thread-safe, efficient, transactional manner while handling concurrency conflicts.

Complicated queries often involve a combination of both indexed scans and sequential scans.